# Can't get input validation Javascript to work

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, submit

Apologies if this question isn't layed out correctly (my first time using stack overflow).
I'm trying to validate if my inputs on a form are filled in when a user presses submit, it alerts the user when the inputs are empty but also when they are not, I'm not sure whats going wrong. Here is my Javascript:

```
<script>
   function validation() {
     var x = document.forms["bookingForm"]["id"].value;
     if (x == "") {
       alert("Ensure all fileds are filled");
       return false;
     } else {
       sendSMS();
       alert("Success");
       return true;
     }
      }
</script>
```

Here is a link to an expanded part of the code for reference:https://pastebin.com/Dj5fA3gB

Comment: What is the value of `x`?

Comment: Why dont you add required to each input like this?
<input type="text" name="example" required>

Comment: @Keff x is equal to the input data.

Comment: @Aaron I've added that as it is useful but it doesn't solve the problem I'm having.

Comment: On second thoughts, adding required nullifies the validation. Thank you.

Comment: So is this the right answer? Gonna post an answer then since I'd always prefer a clean solution with as least code as possible

Answer (score 0):

If you are using submitButton as in  and you are calling validation on onSubmit of the form then you need to call event.preventDefault();

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form onsubmit="validation()" name="bookingForm">
  First Name: <input type="text" name="id" value="Donald"><br>
  Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Duck">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
function validation() {
  event.preventDefault();
         var x = document.forms["bookingForm"]["id"].value;
         if (x == "") {
           alert("Ensure all fileds are filled");
           return false;
         } else {
           sendSMS();
           alert("Success");
           return true;
         }
      }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I changed my code to work as you described here but the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax for accessing a form element and element's value are:

```
document.forms[number].elements[number]


document.forms[number].elements[number].value
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'number', what would that relate to in the code for a form?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in my comment the most clean solution is to use the html attribute required by adding it to your inputs.

Looks something like this.

```html
<form>
 <input type="text" name="example" required>
 <input type="submit" name="send">
</form>
```

The biggest advantage is that it works without any additional JS which is in my opinion always the prefered solution.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include return keyword in the form tag and adding unnecessary keyword "name" in the form tag.

```
<form onsubmit="return validation()" method="POST"
                    action="">
```

remove the "name" attribute from form tag and add action attribute. 
Within the parenthesis in the action attribute, mention what happen if your validation success
Ex:(this code help you understand "action" attribute)

```
<form onsubmit="return productsvalidationform();" method="POST"
                    action="AddProductServlet">
```

when the form was successfully validated, I directed to AddProductServlet.(AddProductServlet is JSP servlet).
so that mention where do you need to redirect.